# php search box with double dropdown list

Tags: php

Here is the updated code.

### classifieds table

### id | title | description | state_id | city_id |

### 1   Ford   | ford for sell|  1       |    1

2 Ford     | ford explorer| 2        |    1

### state table

### id | name |

1   Texas
2   Arizona

city table

---

### id   | name      | state_id

1     Arlington   1
2     Globe       2

The code that does the search and prints the results is all here:

So this file called search.php

```
enter  <?php
   $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
  $db = mysql_select_db('files',$conn);
  $input = $_GET['query'];
  $state = $_POST['state'];
 $city = $_POST['city'];
 if (isset($input) && $input != "" ) {
 $select = "SELECT * FROM classifieds";
 $where = " WHERE (title like '%" . $input . "%'  OR description like '%" . $input .   

 "%')";
if (!empty($city)) {
$select .= " LEFT JOIN city ON classifieds.city_id=city.id";
$where .= " AND city.name = '" . $city . "'";
}
if (!empty($state)) {        
$select .= " LEFT JOIN state ON classifieds.state_id=state.id";
$where .= " AND state.name = '" . $state . "'";
}    
$q = $select . $where . ' ORDER BY date DESC';
$r = mysql_query($q);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($r);
}
echo $rows; ?> Search Results For: <?PHP echo $input; 
if ($rows > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$description = $row['description'];
echo "  <tr  >
<td ><a href='classified-" . $row['adid'] . ".htm' >" . $row['title'] . "</a><br />
 <span><em><a href='category-" . $cat . ".php'>" . $catname . "</a></em><br/>" .    
$description . "...</span></td>
 </tr>
  ";
  }
   }
  ?>
   <form action="search.php" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="query" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search" />
   <select name="state" >
<option value="null"></option>
<?php
//POPULATE DROP DOWN MENU WITH STATES FROM A GIVEN REGION, COUNTRY
$sql = "SELECT id, statename FROM state";
$states = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($states))
{
    echo ("<option value=".$row[id]." >$row[statename]</option>");
}
?>
</select>
<select name="city" >
<option value="null"></option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, city FROM city  ";
$cities = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cities))
{
    echo ("<option value=".$row[id].">$row[city]</option>");
}
?>  here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to check if `state` and/or `city` are set (by the way, you have `GET` set as a method in form, yet you check `$_POST` for city and state - is that correct?) and add them to sql query accordingly:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM classifieds";
$where = " WHERE (title like '%" . $input . "%'  OR description like '%" . $input . "%')";

if (!empty($city)) {
    $select .= " LEFT JOIN city ON classifieds.city_id=city.id";
    $where .= " AND city.name = '" . $city . "'";
}

if (!empty($state)) {        
    $select .= " LEFT JOIN state ON classifieds.state_id=state.id";
    $where .= " AND state.name = '" . $state . "'";
}    

$q = $select . $where . ' ORDER BY date DESC';
```

Note the parentheses for title and description - without them OR would take precendence over AND.

As a sidenote, you don't need to query database twice for the same data.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The thing is it still gives me the results as those dropdowns aren't there. I mean it doesn't filter the search. Like I want to look for an ad in Washington, I don't want other ads from different states to appear in the result. I fell I am almost there thou,

Comment: if (!empty($city)) {
    $q .= " AND city = '" . $city . "'";
}

if (!empty($state)) {
    $q .= " AND state = '" . $state . "'";
}    
Do I have to call state and city database to use this code. Because in my classifieds table I only have state_id and city_id

Comment: Still shows all the records. Ok, lets say Arizona has an id=1, Texas id=2 in the table state, and respectively Allen id=1, Mesa id=2 from table city. In classifieds table I have id, title, description, state_id, city_id. So, let's say I'm looking for a GM. In classifieds table it would be, id=1 , title=GM, description=GMwhatever1, state_id=1, city_id=1. And I have another GM in different state: id=2 , title=GM, description=GMwhatever2, state_id=2, city_id=2. If I want to search for a GM in Arizona only, I don't want the GM from Texas to appear, so far I get every GM even if I chose a state.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($state, $city )` after setting them up in the beginning? Are they set correctly?

Comment: $state and $city are the <select></select> names. I populated them from database, and I able the choose states and cities.It's in the code I posted all the way up. Somehow I tried to change the get method to post in a form, but the above code throws an error.

Comment: Are you sure `$state` and `$city` values are really set by the script? If all three variables should be set from that one form, then stick to either $_GET or $_POST (in the latter you'd need to change method in form).

Comment: I don't know what you mean $state and $city values are set by the script!!!! Like I said, I tried to change all to $_POST and the code you provided throws an error: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in $rows = mysql_num_rows($r);. I am going crazy here...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11607/discussion-between-bjauy-and-rocks)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would share the solution Bjauy gave me :)

```
  $select = "SELECT * FROM classifieds";
      $where = " WHERE (title like '%" . $input . "%'   OR description like '%" .  

       $input . "%' )";
          if (!empty($state)) {        

        $where .= " AND state_id = '" . $state . "'";
        }
       if (!empty($city)) {

        $where .= " AND city_id = '" . $city . "'";
       } 
     $query = $select . $where . ' ORDER BY date DESC';
```